# Java: constructor does not return. But it does or is it?

Tags: java

statement_1: whenever ones defines constructor of a class skip the return type i.e constructor does not return anything. So even it cannot be declared void.

statement_2: But when `classname obj = new classname()` encountered JVM creates a object and *returns* a reference to the `obj` variable.

Both these statements are true. Now i want to know how statement_2 is related to statement_1.

my question is how `obj` is initialized if constructor does not return anything? means it does return something then it should have return type of class.

```
class Myclass{
              Myclass Myclass(){
                                   //return something of Myclass type 
               }

}
```

then `Myclass obj = new Myclass()` shouldn't it would have made more sense.

Shed more light on the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rule. A constructor doesn't have a return type. When you call `new Foo()` you are using the `new` operator followed by a constructor invocation.

It's the `new` operator which *makes up the expression* and returns an object of type `Foo`.

If the constructor had a return type, you'd be able to write

```
Foo something = Foo();
```

or just (assuming return `void`)

```
Foo();
```

but both these pieces of codes are illegal. A constructor invocation must **always** be preceded by the `new` operator. The `new` operator creates a an object of type `Foo` (allocating space for storage for example), passes this object to the constructor to *initialize* it, and finally returns the initialized instance to the caller.

You may wonder why the object creation syntax is so closer to a normal method invocation. I guess it's to allow argument to be passed to the constructor. They could have made a special syntax like

```
Foo foo = new Foo
```

note the missing parenthesis, so this doesn't resemble a method invocation. However, how would you pass arguments to the constructor? Maybe simply by listing them

```
Foo foo = new Foo "Hello", "World"
```

but this syntax conflicts with that to initialize two or more variables in a single statement, ie

```
Number a = new Integer(12), b = new Float(1.2);
```

so they eventually chose that syntax.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `classname obj = new classname()`, it is the `new` operator that creates and returns the object. The constructor is used to initialise it (e.g. setting any fields) so does not return anything.

You can think of it as 3 steps

1. `new` creates the object
2. `new` calls the constructor on the object it has just created
3. `new` returns the object that was created

You can read more about [object creation in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 0):

here constructor is not returning anything, this statement just returning the address of memory where obj object is allocated. & it is the work of new operator, tht's why we need new operator here

Answer (score 0):

Constructors don't return anything. constructors are meant to initialize your instance variables. when you say

```
    Foo f = new Foo();
```

**new** operator creates a Foo object.

Answer (score 0):

Even at the byte code level, a constructor doesn't return anything. It has the same return type as a method which returns `void`  Instead it takes the object as an argument as `this` to initialise.

Note: there is no option return a different object which is why a factory methods can be required.